# Docker Unknown flag --mount

Tags: docker, containers, mount

I want to mount a directory from the host to a container using the mount `flag` over `volume` but I am getting ` This is only experienced when using mount flag and not with volume

```
*Command:*
    docker run -d  -it  --name devtest --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/home/  httpd
```

> **Error**   unknown flag: --mount

```
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: aufs
Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
Volume: local
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: "deleted" 
Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.10.0-42-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 17.04
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.715 GiB
Name: "deleted"
ID: "deleted"
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`docker run` support for the `--mount` option was only introduced in Docker [17.06](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/#choosing-the--v-or-mount-flag). You are using Docker `1.13.1`. You have two choices:

1. Update to Docker `17.06` or later if you can;
2. Use the `-v` approach to bind mount the volume you require e.g. `docker run -v $(pwd):/home`

Comment: Seems like Ubuntu repo has outdated version, will try to build from source or see if I can get updated repo. Thanks

Comment: For people arriving in the future, find instructions for adding the proper docker repository here:
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
The default docker.io package on apt is out of date.

Comment: Interesting.. the version you get from get.docker.com, which is their official, endorsed way, is still 1.13.1. This is as of today, Aug 16, 2018, running the latest version of Fedora Atomic.

Comment: You also need `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`

Comment: I had this error in Docker 19.03
You may need to add `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental` to the first line of your Docker file.