# Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error Unknown flag: mount

Tags: docker, dockerfile

There is a previous question ([Docker Unknown flag --mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167955/docker-unknown-flag-mount)) facing the same error that was due to having an out-of-date version of Docker running. I have an up-to-date version of Docker running.

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/myrepo/myproject.git@develop
RUN conda install numpy
...
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds), I should be able to simply run `docker build --ssh default .`. However, I receive the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 3: Unknown flag: mount
```

Output of `docker version`:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:39 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

I would like to build a Docker image without exposing my private SSH credentials, and this seemed to be the supported method. Anyone have thoughts on what's causing the issue?

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone trying to get this functionality to work: at the time of this writing, if you're running Docker from a Mac (or Windows, I assume), you cannot pass your SSH client to the docker container during the build process, so this functionality won't work for you.

Comment: @Thomasleveil's answer is great, although I also needed to upgrade **docker-compose** from 1.24.0 to 1.26.2 before I could get this to work.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

## tl;dr

**Dockerfile**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/myrepo/myproject.git@develop
RUN conda install numpy
...
```

***Note:** the comment on the first line is [required voodoo](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#overriding-default-frontends)*

Then build your docker image with:

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default -t my_image .
```

With this, you will be able to use the [`--mount` option](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md#experimental-syntaxes) for the `RUN` directive in your Dockerfile.

---

## Long answer

As found in the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#external-implementation-features), *ssh forwarding* when building docker image is enabled only when using the [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#buildkit) backend:

> ### External implementation features
>
> This feature is only available when using the
> [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#buildkit)
> backend.
>
> Docker build supports experimental features like cache mounts, build
> secrets and ssh forwarding that are enabled by using an external
> implementation of the builder with a syntax directive. To learn about
> these features, [refer to the documentation in BuildKit
> repository](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md).

For this you need **Docker 18.09** (or later) and you also need to run the `docker build` command with the **`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`** environment variable and start your Docker file with the following **magic comment** : `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental`.

Also you can edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add :

```json
{
    "experimental" : false,
    "debug" : true,
    "features": {
        "buildkit" : true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this, and got a new error: `failed to create LLB definition: Dockerfile parse error line 3: Unknown flag: mount`.

Comment: Turns out I had to put the following header in my Dockerfile: `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.0.0-experimental`. Now I'm getting failure on host key verification. Making progress!

Comment: oh, I missed that, I will update my answer so it is clearer for futur readers

Comment: 2 hours , 2 hours and finally i need put this comment in my Dockerfile
`# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental`

Comment: This answer should have so much more appreciation.

Comment: Why does it work without this comment line locally but on a GitLab CI job it requires that magical comment?

Comment: @eric.frederich Unsure personally. It may be that you have a newer version of Docker on your local, and that the syntax has been promoted from experimental? Been a while since I've done any work with Docker/Kubernetes.

Answer (score 10):

To anyone out there that might be struggling with this sort of error: ensure that the first line of the file is '# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental'. This will work:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM golang:1.14.1 as builder

...    

RUN --mount=type=ssh  GOSUMDB=off go get -d -v ./...
```

BUT if you add a comment at the start of the file like so:

```
# SOME SILLY COMMENT HERE  <--- this ostensibly innocent comment ruins everything!

# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM golang:1.14.1 as builder

...    

RUN --mount=type=ssh  GOSUMDB=off go get -d -v ./...
```

Then 'syntax=...' will not be taken into account because it's no longer on the very first line. This is why you get that weird error about 'mount' below! Gah!

Hopefully this will save a few hours from the lives of a few people.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using `sudo` for docker commands, you might need:

`sudo DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 ...`

Comment: And using the sudo after variable does not work haha just wasted hours before realising this.

Answer (score 6):

The error message that you are getting due to writing `--mount` inside the `Dockerfile`. You have to enable Docker BuildKit first in order to use this syntax.

You can check all of the currently available build options through [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

Comment: Too bad that at the moment the Bocker BuildKit commands are not available through Docker Compose. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6440

Comment: @AlexisWilke Well use of Buildkit in general is possible with Docker Compose. Just run it with : `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker-compose build`. It seems that the special `--mount` arguments such as build time secrets (https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/7046) or ssh (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7252) are not part of it yet.

Comment: `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 ` still has the error with Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

Answer (score 1):

Locally I just needed DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build...

In TeamCity build pipeline my docker file still needed the magic line to overcome this issue.  My TeamCity agent is running Docker version 19.03.9

So in 2022 this is still my conclusion:

1. Try the magic line mentioned at the top of your Docker file:
   #syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
2. Use BUILDKIT. e.g. DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1

.. and in my context this is all for running the following line:

RUN --mount=type=ssh npm install "git+ssh://git@github.com:dra_____.git"

Maybe this will save some folks some time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone:

I was also facing the similar issue,

`failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: Dockerfile parse error line 11: Unknown flag: mount`

I was using `Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d`

I just updated this to `docker 20.10.24`