# Using a pip cache directory in docker builds

Tags: python, docker, caching, pip, continuous-integration

I'm hoping to get my `pip install` instructions inside my `docker build`s as fast as possible.

I've read [many](https://www.aptible.com/documentation/deploy/tutorials/faq/dockerfile-caching/pip-dockerfile-caching.html) [posts](https://vsupalov.com/speed-up-python-docker-image-build/) explaining how adding your `requirements.txt` before the rest of the app helps you take advantage of Docker's own image cache if your `requirements.txt` hasn't changed. But this is no help at all when dependencies do change, even slightly.

The next step would be if we could use a consistent pip cache directory. By default, `pip` will cache downloaded packages in `~/.cache/pip` (on Linux), and so if you're ever installing the same version of a module that has been installed before anywhere on the system, it shouldn't need to go and download it again, but instead simply use the cached version. If we could leverage a shared cache directory for docker builds, this could help speed up dependency installs a lot.

However, there doesn't appear to be any simple way to mount a volume while running `docker build`. The build environment seems to be basically impenetrable. I found [one article](https://medium.com/@scythargon/cache-for-python-pip-downloads-and-wheels-in-docker-67f24e7cd84e) suggesting a genius but complex method of running an `rsync` server on the host and then, with a hack inside the build to get the host IP, rsyncing the pip cache in from the host. But I'm not relishing the idea of running an rsync server in Jenkins (which isn't the most secure platform at the best of times).

Does anyone know if there's any other way to achieve a shared cache volume more simply?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have the cache inside your docker image layer?

Comment: No I don't. I want to be able to use a shared cache which I can share at build time.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I suggest you to use [buildkit](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md), also see [this](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/).

**Dockerfile:**

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install pyyaml
```

**NOTE**: `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental` is a must，you have to add it at the beginning of Dockerfile to enable this feature.

**1.**

**The first execute build:**

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
docker build --progress=plain -t abc:1 . --no-cache
```

**The first log:**

```
#9 [stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install...
#9   digest: sha256:55b70da1cbbe4d424f8c50c0678a01e855510bbda9d26f1ac5b983808f3bf4a5
#9 name: "[stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install pyyaml"
#9  started: 2019-09-20 03:11:35.296107357 +0000 UTC
#9 1.955 Collecting pyyaml
#9 3.050   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/e8/b3212641ee2718d556df0f23f78de8303f068fe29cdaa7a91018849582fe/PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265kB)
#9 5.006 Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml
#9 5.007   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): started
#9 5.249   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#9 5.250   Created wheel for pyyaml: filename=PyYAML-5.1.2-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl size=44104 sha256=867daf35eab43c2d047ad737ea1e9eaeb4168b87501cd4d62c533f671208acaa
#9 5.250   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d9/45/dd/65f0b38450c47cf7e5312883deb97d065e030c5cca0a365030
#9 5.267 Successfully built pyyaml
#9 5.274 Installing collected packages: pyyaml
#9 5.309 Successfully installed pyyaml-5.1.2
#9completed: 2019-09-20 03:11:42.221146294 +0000 UTC
#9 duration: 6.925038937s
```

From above, you can see the first time, the build will download pyyaml from internet.

**2.**

**The second execute build:**

```
docker build --progress=plain -t abc:1 . --no-cache
```

**The second log:**

```
#9 [stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install...
#9   digest: sha256:55b70da1cbbe4d424f8c50c0678a01e855510bbda9d26f1ac5b983808f3bf4a5
#9 name: "[stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install pyyaml"
#9  started: 2019-09-20 03:16:58.588157354 +0000 UTC
#9 1.786 Collecting pyyaml
#9 2.234 Installing collected packages: pyyaml
#9 2.270 Successfully installed pyyaml-5.1.2
#9completed: 2019-09-20 03:17:01.933398002 +0000 UTC
#9 duration: 3.345240648s
```

From above, you can see the build no longer download package from internet, just use the cache. NOTE, this is not the traditional docker build cache as I have use `--no-cache`, it's `/root/.cache/pip` which I mount into build.

**3.**

**The third execute build which delete buildkit cache:**

```
docker builder prune
docker build --progress=plain -t abc:1 . --no-cache
```

**The third log:**

```
#9 [stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install...
#9   digest: sha256:55b70da1cbbe4d424f8c50c0678a01e855510bbda9d26f1ac5b983808f3bf4a5
#9 name: "[stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install pyyaml"
#9  started: 2019-09-20 03:19:07.434792944 +0000 UTC
#9 1.894 Collecting pyyaml
#9 2.740   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/e8/b3212641ee2718d556df0f23f78de8303f068fe29cdaa7a91018849582fe/PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265kB)
#9 3.319 Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml
#9 3.319   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): started
#9 3.560   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#9 3.560   Created wheel for pyyaml: filename=PyYAML-5.1.2-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl size=44104 sha256=cea5bc4689e231df7915c2fc3abca225d4ee2e869a7540682aacb6d42eb17053
#9 3.560   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d9/45/dd/65f0b38450c47cf7e5312883deb97d065e030c5cca0a365030
#9 3.580 Successfully built pyyaml
#9 3.585 Installing collected packages: pyyaml
#9 3.622 Successfully installed pyyaml-5.1.2
#9completed: 2019-09-20 03:19:12.530742712 +0000 UTC
#9 duration: 5.095949768s
```

From above, you can see if delete buildkit cache, the package download again.

In a word, it will give you a shared cache between several times build, and this cache will only be mounted when image build. But, the image self will not have these cache, so avoid a lots of intermediate layer in image.

EDIT for folks who are using docker compose and are lazy to read the comments...:

> You can also do this with docker-compose if you set
> COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1. For example: COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1
> DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker-compose build –

**UPDATE according to folk's question 2020/09/02:**

I don't know from which version (my version now is 19.03.11), if not specify `mode` for cache directory, the cache won't be reused by next time build.

Don't know the detail reason, but you could add `mode=0755,` to Dockerfile to make it work again:

**Dockerfile:**

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN --mount=type=cache,mode=0755,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install pyyaml
```

**UPDATE according to folk's question 2023/04/23:**

**Q:** Where is the cache exactly on the host?

**A:** The cache on host is maintained by docker with an overlay. You could use next command `docker buildx du --verbose` and find a entry type `Type:           exec.cachemount`, after that you got the `ID: ntpjzcz8hhx31b80nwxji05hn`:

```
ID:             ntpjzcz8hhx31b80nwxji05hn
Created at:     2023-04-23 01:36:41.102680066 +0000 UTC
Mutable:        true
Reclaimable:    true
Shared:         false
Size:           3.601MB
Description:    cached mount /root/.cache/pip from exec /bin/sh -c pip install pyyaml
Usage count:    2
Last used:      7 minutes ago
Type:           exec.cachemount
```

Afterwards, go to `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ntpjzcz8hhx31b80nwxji05hn/diff/cache/wheels` to find the cached pyyaml (depends on the ID you got from above). For my station, it looks like next:

> root@shdebian1:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ntpjzcz8hhx31b80nwxji05hn/diff/cache/wheels/81/5a/02/b3447894318b70e3cbff3cb4f1a50d9d50a848185358de1d71# ls
>
> PyYAML-6.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

Comment: This looks like *exactly* what I was looking for. I'll give it a try and accept if it works as described.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank-you so much. One minor point - even though you included it in your example, I missed the significance of the `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental` line and so didn't copy it. Ended up at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153089/error-response-from-daemon-dockerfile-parse-error-unknown-flag-mount to correct my mistake. You might want to just emphasise the need for that line in your answer.

Comment: I just came back to this question and remembered how much I appreciated it. Then I found this - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288643/why-cant-a-bounty-created-to-reward-an-existing-answer-be-awarded-immediately - and I think I'm going to award you 100 bounty for giving me exactly what I wanted =) But it looks like it'll take 24 hours before I can award it.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly that this won't reuse hosts pip cache?

Comment: Won't reuse the hosts pip cache, internal manged a cache to reuse among different rebuild.

Comment: @atline I have different docker services which uses similar requirements.txt. Their Dockerfiles are same. Is it possible to make them able to share pip cache between each other?

Comment: @Mr.D Yes, it can, as long as you did not specify different `id` in dockerfile, all `target=/root/.cache/pip` in different Dockerfile means the same thing, that is `mount a same docker maintained cache folder to target/root/.cache/pip`. If this not you want, you could use `target=/root/.cache/pip,id=myid` to distinguish cache name. If no `id` specified, just means same id.

Comment: @atline I am copy-pasting the example is the answer but its always downloading the file for me. My Docker version is 19.03.8 (build afacb8b). I am on MacOS Catalina. 

Even on Second Run it's like:
```#7 [stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install...
#7 1.477 Collecting pyyaml
#7 1.764   Downloading PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)```

Comment: @atline have added the problem as a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61459775/1060337

Comment: @codersofthedark See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61474441/6394722

Comment: You can also do this with `docker-compose` if you set `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1`. For example:  `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker-compose build`

Comment: hi @atline, do you know if DOCKER_BUILDKIT can be enabled using Docker SDK for Python?

Comment: @RytisJonynas I guess can't currently, see https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2230

Comment: @atline I followed your answer on my VM just with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. It worked well initially, however after a while the docker experimental image build would once again start downloading from PyPi. 
I thought it's because of the system cache gets cleared / invalidated. So I cleaned docker build cache and changed cache directory param in mount command to `/home/my_user/newcachedir/`, however, now docker experimental image build installs everything either from network or old cache dir (`/home/my_user/.cache/pip`). Any ideas why and how to make it work with new dir for cache?

Comment: @atline I posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63046991/11268971. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this still work? I'm trying this now, and it's still downloading my dependencies.

Comment: @afagarap YES, your are correct, I tried it, looks with new docker, a `mode` parameter need to be added, see updated answer.

Comment: @atline Cool. Thanks. I'll try it, and let you know what I get.

Comment: Seems that, using Docker 20.10.2, is not working any more

Comment: @Cesar I confirmed it works for 20.10.2 on my side.

Comment: Is there any similar way to do this without using BuildKit?

Comment: This works without `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental` comment using Docker 20.10.6 and docker-compose 1.27.4.

Comment: I also needed to add the `uid=1234` option to the mount because by default "cache" mounts as root:root, and since my dockerfile doesn't run as root, pip refused to use the cache until I changed the uid.  Otherwise, it worked like a charm!

Comment: I am confused about the `/root/.cache` directory. Is that location in my Docker container or in my main machine? Why does /root/.cache work? Is it specific to pip?

Comment: @cozos YES, `$HOME/.cache/pip` is the cache of pip to cache the downloaded package, you could use `pip3 cache dir` to verify it. When docker build, there will a build container there with `root` as account, so when docker build, the pip package downloaded to `/root/.cache`. Buildkit will store that on host, and when you rebuild, that dir will remount to build container, then you no need to download the package again.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense with `pip3 cache dir`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `mode=0755,` - hidden gem, thank you!

Comment: @atline "Buildkit will store that on host" - is that persistent on docker restarts?

Comment: @jtlz2 Yes, persistent on host even `systemctl restart docker`

Comment: @atline Just to be clear, where exactly will it store it on the host? In `$HOME/.cache/pip`?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś As it's too long, see my new edit in answer.