# Docker BuildKit --mount=type=cache not working, why?

Tags: macos, docker, caching, pip, docker-buildkit

I am trying to implement [Buildkit's cache mount feature.](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md#run---mounttypecache)

My Dockerfile is:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install pyyaml
```

CMD: `docker build --progress=plain -t abc:1 . --no-cache`

**First Run Output:**

```
#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 175B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#3 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental
#3 DONE 2.8s

#4 docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental@sha256:787107d7f...
#4 CACHED

#5 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.6-alpine
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [stage-0 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.6-alpine
#6 CACHED

#7 [stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install...
#7 1.410 Collecting pyyaml
#7 1.731   Downloading PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)
#7 2.470 Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml
#7 2.471   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): started
#7 2.801   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#7 2.802   Created wheel for pyyaml: filename=PyYAML-5.3.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl size=44621 sha256=0bfa8470e677b8c2e1d50f8749aa5890b5fb7d7d15352596fbd928c846f9922d
#7 2.802   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e5/9d/ad/2ee53cf262cba1ffd8afe1487eef788ea3f260b7e6232a80fc
#7 2.803 Successfully built pyyaml
#7 2.835 Installing collected packages: pyyaml
#7 2.882 Successfully installed pyyaml-5.3.1
#7 DONE 3.3s

#8 exporting to image
#8 exporting layers
#8 exporting layers 0.1s done
#8 writing image sha256:d7ecd86c64611e14f55fa2d31b8f440246e356026eef7175526ccc921373c205 done
#8 naming to docker.io/library/abc:1 done
#8 DONE 0.1s
```

**Second Run Output:**

```
#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 37B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental
#3 DONE 2.7s

#4 docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental@sha256:787107d7f...
#4 CACHED

#5 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.6-alpine
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [stage-0 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.6-alpine
#6 CACHED

#7 [stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install...
#7 1.385 Collecting pyyaml
#7 1.773   Downloading PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)
#7 2.517 Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml
#7 2.518   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): started
#7 2.844   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#7 2.846   Created wheel for pyyaml: filename=PyYAML-5.3.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl size=44621 sha256=064a160d2f195ad7753fba5abf9481b40b515fadffc94f30aef20146209a0faa
#7 2.846   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e5/9d/ad/2ee53cf262cba1ffd8afe1487eef788ea3f260b7e6232a80fc
#7 2.846 Successfully built pyyaml
#7 2.877 Installing collected packages: pyyaml
#7 2.920 Successfully installed pyyaml-5.3.1
#7 DONE 3.3s

#8 exporting to image
#8 exporting layers
#8 exporting layers 0.1s done
#8 writing image sha256:42525b426b00a8728b735c15efb96bd237fc020f46d6d99f5bfebb7758016e71 done
#8 naming to docker.io/library/abc:1 done
#8 DONE 0.1s
```

**Expected:**

In the second run, I was expecting `pyyaml` to be picked from the cache.

OS: 
Mac OS Catalina (10.15.3)

Docker Version:

[image]

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58021389/1060337

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could add `mode=0777` for example to `Dockerfile` to make it work.

**Dockerfile:**

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN --mount=type=cache,mode=0777,target=/root/.cache/pip pip install pyyaml
```

Here,

> mode: File mode for new cache directory in octal. Default 0755.

**The 1st run:**

```
#8 [stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,mode=0777,target=/root/.cache/pip p...
#8 2.085 Collecting pyyaml
#8 2.455   Downloading PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)
#8 3.484 Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml
#8 3.485   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): started
#8 3.864   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#8 3.865   Created wheel for pyyaml: filename=PyYAML-5.3.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl size=44621 sha256=372ab164f3e88d66fa2571fa048317b22a7c48bf723dfecbac4e058e9037c4fd
#8 3.865   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e5/9d/ad/2ee53cf262cba1ffd8afe1487eef788ea3f260b7e6232a80fc
#8 3.866 Successfully built pyyaml
#8 3.901 Installing collected packages: pyyaml
#8 3.961 Successfully installed pyyaml-5.3.1
#8 DONE 4.7s
```

**The 2nd run:**

```
#8 [stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,mode=0777,target=/root/.cache/pip p...
#8 2.069 Processing /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e5/9d/ad/2ee53cf262cba1ffd8afe1487eef788ea3f260b7e6232a80fc/PyYAML-5.3.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
#8 2.112 Installing collected packages: pyyaml
#8 2.166 Successfully installed pyyaml-5.3.1
#8 DONE 2.5s
```

**UPDATE:**

If I use next for experiment:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip ls -alh /root/.cache/pip;pip install pyyaml;ls -alh /root/.cache/pip
```

I could see next:

```
#7 [stage-0 2/2] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip ls -alh /ro...
#7 0.405 total 8K
#7 0.405 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Apr 29 01:04 .
#7 0.405 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Apr 29 01:04 ..
#7 1.957 Collecting pyyaml
#7 2.572   Downloading PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)
#7 3.552 Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml
#7 3.553   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): started
#7 3.885   Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#7 3.887   Created wheel for pyyaml: filename=PyYAML-5.3.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl size=44621 sha256=4c971f0f901ff8ed3a20c5bb7d94069f15249c665ebe611430db17cb87969cc7
#7 3.887   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e5/9d/ad/2ee53cf262cba1ffd8afe1487eef788ea3f260b7e6232a80fc
#7 3.888 Successfully built pyyaml
#7 3.918 Installing collected packages: pyyaml
#7 3.972 Successfully installed pyyaml-5.3.1
#7 4.451 WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1 is available.
#7 4.451 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
#7 4.512 total 20K
#7 4.512 drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root        4.0K Apr 29 01:04 .
#7 4.512 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Apr 29 01:04 ..
#7 4.512 drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root        4.0K Apr 29 01:04 http
#7 4.512 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Apr 29 01:04 selfcheck
#7 4.512 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Apr 29 01:04 wheels
#7 DONE 4.7s
```

Rerun above again, the things same. So looks like if not set `mode`, the buildkit won't mount a cache from docker host. But if set a mode `mode`, even with `0755`, it's ok.

So, now I strongly guess it's a bug of buildkit on MACOS, that is: if not set `mode`, it will not mount cache for you. But the behavior is ok on linux.

Comment: @altine: One more question: where on the host os (mac in my case) I can check this cache directory. Also, is it possible to populate the cash outside of docker context?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot for build, there is also a build container there, so the build process should be in hyperkit on macos, so should not related to macos filesystem permission. I update the answer. For your new question, sorry, I really don't know, even on linux, I can just see `cache.db  content  executor  metadata.db  snapshots.db` under buildkit folder. You may ask another question to see if others could help.

Comment: I can confirm this is still broken on my non-M-series Mac with Ventura in 2023. Never would have figured it out since there is no error message. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I test docker build at ubuntu, and has the same bug. If not set mode, the cache doesn't work.

build command

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --progress=plain --no-cache --secret id=git,src=$PWD/gitconfig -f Dockerfile -t app .
```

Dockerfile

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM golang:1.16.5 as builder

WORKDIR /code

COPY . .

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=git,target=/root/.gitconfig,required=true,mode=0666 \
    --mount=type=cache,mode=0777,id=gocache,target=/root/.cache/go-build \
    --mount=type=cache,mode=0777,id=gomodcache,target=/go/pkg/mod \
    ls -lha /root/.cache/go-build && \
        ls -lha /go/pkg/mod && \
    GO_ENABLE="0" go build -o app -v main.go && \
        ls -lha /root/.cache/go-build && \
        ls -lha /go/pkg/mod


FROM ubuntu:20.04

COPY --from=builder /code/app /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT app
```

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:           20.10.2
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.8
 Git commit:        20.10.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
 Built:             Tue Mar 30 21:24:57 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.2
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.8
  Git commit:       20.10.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
  Built:            Mon Mar 29 19:10:09 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0~rc95-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```