# Installation with pip in Docker fails to find module

Tags: python, docker, pip

I have the following in my `setup.py`

```
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my-app=main:run',
        ],
```

and my file structure is

```
▶ tree -L 2
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── redis.conf
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── bfile.py
│   └── afile.py
```

and in my `main.py`

```
def run():
    actual_run()
```

Locally, in a virtualenv when performing

```
pip install -e . && my-app
```

it runs smoothly.

However in an image created with the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
RUN pip3 install .

CMD [ "my-app"]
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/my-app", line 5, in <module>
    from main import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

What I noticed, is that in my image, in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/` there only the a file named `my-app-0.0.1.dist-info` and not a dir with the source files.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give a minimal workable `setup.py`, but next could works, FYI:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
RUN pip3 install .

CMD [ "my-app"]
```

**setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="my-app",
    version="0.0.1",

    packages=['main'],
    package_dir={'main':'src'},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my-app=main.main:run',
        ],
    }
)
```

**src/main.py:**

```
def run():
    print("hello world")
```

**Execution:**

```
# docker build -t abc:1 .
# docker run --rm abc:1
hello world
```

**Explain:**

In above, `src` folder will map to `main` module, and `packages=['main']` specify the python package name which will be installed into `site-packages`.

In final image, the package will be located as next:

```
root@7b5ce63d8226:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/main# ls
__pycache__  main.py
```

So, you need to use `main.main:run` to call your function.

Comment: Copying in just the requirements file and then doing a pip install first is the standard approach, but if you do that the folder doesn't exist and you'll get an error. Is there a workaround without having to `COPY . .` before pip install?

Comment: I failed to catch your idea, `COPY . .` is used to let container see source code.

Comment: When I do a pip install (with an entrypoints config like this) before copying in the project's files, when I launch the container and run the `console_scripts` I configured I get a error it can't find the module. I think thats because the folder wasn't there during install so it couldn't create the link?

Comment: So why you don't want to do `COPY . .`? Only have source code or prebuilt package, you can install the package, only install the package you could possible use setuptools to install `my-app` command to `/usr/local/bin` or similar folder. I'm sorry I really can't catch your idea. If you care that, I suggest you send a full example and errors to a new post...

Comment: You mean idea of optimizing the docker layer caching? If so "python dockerfile best practices" will turn up a bunch of better explanations than I could give, for example: https://testdriven.io/blog/docker-best-practices/#order-dockerfile-commands-appropriately. Main thing is if you modify source it will trigger a pip install on rebuild- even if you didn't update the deps. Putting the dep files in a separate layer prevents that.

Comment: Ok, so you don't have any new question, you are giving a suggestion? The answer just target to resolve OP's specific problem. If we use in production, we surely can first copy requrements, install it, and then copy source files. If no requiremtns changes, you use the cache now. Just for simple sake, I didn't mention that as this not important for OP's problem. More, if you have requirements changes, you may want to have a look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018300/using-a-pip-cache-directory-in-docker-builds/