# AWS Lambda function and running a small pytorch model

Tags: docker, aws-lambda

I am 6 hours into trying to get a simple AWS Lambda function running with PyTorch via Docker container and am going to cry. Any help would be most appreciated.

My current flavour of not getting this to work is, executing the function and it returns:

> {
> "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_handler': No module named 'torch'",
> "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
> "requestId": "ad81f14d-19de-41c3-9878-6a86aa3cf77e",
> "stackTrace": []
> }

I can see in my terminal it downloads Pytorch

```
#0 5.102   Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-2.2.0%2Bcpu-cp312-cp312-linux_x86_64.whl (186.7 MB)
#0 19.43      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 186.7/186.7 MB 5.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# Define custom function directory
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM python:3.12 as build-image

ARG FUNCTION_DIR

RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}

RUN pip install --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html -r ${FUNCTION_DIR}/requirements.txt

RUN pip install \
    --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
    awslambdaric

FROM python:3.12-slim

ARG FUNCTION_DIR

WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]

CMD [ "lambda_handler.handler" ]
```

Here are my requirements.txt

```
Pillow==10.1.0
requests==2.31.0
torch==2.2.0+cpu
torchvision
```

Comment: You `pip install` system-wide. Only `lambdaric` is installed into function directory, the rest is installed into your system site-packages and is not copied to the final stage image. Try `pip install --target $FUNCTION_DIR` both for requirements and lambdaric, or just use a virtual environment and copy it to the same path of the final stage.

Comment: Btw, I'd recommend mounting a pip cache volume during build to speed up local development as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018300/using-a-pip-cache-directory-in-docker-builds

Comment: @STerliakov thank you very much for your informative responses, it got me out of a bind.