# Docker mount files and volumes to relative path without using UNIX/Windows-specific syntax

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to write a Docker image for a Discord bot that can run both on my Windows PC for testing and Linux server for production use. I want to be able to Git pull my code on any OS, edit a configuration file in this repository, then simply do `docker-compose up` to build and run my image (which accesses the configuration file; I don't want to copy this into the image as I may need to edit this file without editing the code/image itself). However, this seems to not be possible, because I do not have a way of guaranteeing where the directory in which this configuration file is located. I have seen workarounds in the [official Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount) that say you should use `$(pwd)/path/to/file` to access your current directory, however, this only works in UNIX-based systems, and only when using this as an argument of the `docker build` command. Using `$(pwd)` or `%cd%` is not accepted in `docker-compose.yml`, throwing the error:

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '%' that cannot start any token
```

I have also already tried to specify paths such as `path/to/file` and `./path/to/file` in both `docker run -v <volume paths>` and `docker-compose.yml`, to no avail. While no error is thrown when using `./path` in `docker run`, no files or directories can be found in the image when running.

An example of me trying this with docker-compose.yml:
**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine
RUN ls /usr/src/testdir/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    test:
        build: ./
        volumes:
         - ./testdir/:/usr/src/testdir
```

When there's a folder in the same folder as `docker-compose.yml` named `testdir` with one file in here, running the command `docker-compose up` returns:

```
ls: /usr/src/testdir/: No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'test' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c ls /usr/src/testdir/' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Considering the "write-once, run anywhere" mentality of Docker, it dumbfounds me knowing that Docker doesn't provide any easy way to mount volumes by relative path. Is there a way to use a relative path in `docker-compose.yml` and/or `docker run` without the use of OS-specific syntax?

Comment: In Compose specifically, [relative paths for `volumes:` are relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) and should work portably.  Can you provide a [mcve] showing the setup that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze. As a test, I've set up a directory on my Windows computer with the file docker-compose.yml: `version: "3.8"services: test: build: ./ volumes: - ./testdir/:/usr/src/testdir`(Not able to put these new lines in a comment)

Dockerfile: 

`FROM alpine RUN ls /usr/src/testdir/`

And a directory in this same folder named testdir with a single file in this directory. Upon running `docker-compose up`, the following error is outputted:

ls: /usr/src/testdir/: No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'test' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c ls /usr/src/testdir/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### My Solution

My issue wasn't necessarily related to not being able to access relative paths in Docker. Relative paths are usable through `docker run` (this is pointed out by the above solution by Jules Clements and the comment by
user1767316: wrap the volume argument value in double quotes and use `($pwd)`), [relative paths are supported in `docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) as pointed out by David. I was attempting to access this volume during build-time, which isn't possible per my configuration during. I instead will copy the configuration file over during one build-time layer, but use the volume for when the image is running.

#### Other Resources

- [Enable Docker BuildKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153089/error-response-from-daemon-dockerfile-parse-error-unknown-flag-mount)
- [Mount volumes during build using Docker BuildKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050899/how-to-mount-host-volumes-into-docker-containers-in-dockerfile-during-build)

Comment: You do not have to use `%cd%, $(pwd), etc. depending on your OS.` You can use `${pwd}` on all OS using cygwin on windows as long as you surround the volume argument value with double quotes. `docker run --volume "$(pwd)\:/dir/inside/container"  ...`

Comment: @user1767316 Thanks for the comment. I'll include that in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who hits this and wants to know how to use $(pwd), it may save a little time to know you need to quote wrap the entire parameter, e.g.

```
docker run --volume "$(pwd)\:C:/solution/workspace" --env TOKEN=$env:TOKEN cdaf/windows-ado-agent
```

Comment: Works perfectly with cygwin with the same syntax than on linux ! Thanks