# Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error: Unknown flag: link

Tags: docker

I have just clone the [API Platform](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform) project and when I try to build the `Dockerfile` I got the error:
`Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 74: Unknown flag: link`
which correspond to this line in the `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY --link docker/php/conf.d/app.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/
```

Might be a similar error of [Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error Unknown flag: mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153089/error-response-from-daemon-dockerfile-parse-error-unknown-flag-mount) ?

Do you know how to fix this ?

Thank you !

Comment: The post you linked to suggests one cause is an out of date Docker version. `--link` was added in dockerfile syntax v1.4. What version of Docker are you running?

Comment: Docker version 20.10.18, build b40c2f6

Comment: Are you using the classic builder backend or [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#buildkit)? If the latter, you might want to add `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1`

Comment: I'm using the classic build but anyway if you look at the Dockerfile in the Api platform project at the first line `#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4`

Comment: How are you building the image? Are you running `docker compose build` or `docker-compose build`? I get different answers for `docker compose version` and `docker-compose --version` and would always recommend using `docker compose` as that is now standard

Comment: I was using `docker-compose`, I tried with `docker compose` and I don't have the error anymore. Thank you !